# Solutions for the equation $x^{d} = a$ in a finite group implies $(d, |G|) = 1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

As title suggests, I want to show that if the equation $x^{d} = a$ has a solution for every $a\in G$ then $d$ and $|G|$ must be relative primes.

Actually this is an equivalence but the inverse direction is clear but I don't even know how to prove this direction.

Comment: This has been asked here before. I suspect that this question will be closed soon.

Comment: Note that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3078090/104041) is for cyclic groups.

Comment: Yes, a few questions come back from time to time. This question is very popular. There are other popular questions on equations in a group, see  for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069016/number-of-solutions-to-xn-e-in-group-g-is-divisible-by-n), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078090/the-number-of-solutions-to-xk-a-over-g-a-finite-cyclic-group-is-gcdk?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Yes, this is the correct duplicate. @Shaun thank you for changing the close vote.

Comment: Thank you @AnneBauval